# How to pass multiple custom fields as shortcode's parameters

Tags: plugins, wp-query, custom-field, shortcode, metabox

I'm learning how to pass parameters in shorcode, I know the basic step after read through WP Codex.

But for now, I have plugin come with custom fields and as the title, I want to know how to do it.

Here is the code from plugin that adds custom fields

```
$prefix = '_al_listing_';
$fields = [];

$fields[] = [
    'name' => __( 'Price', 'auto-listings' ),
    'id'   => $prefix . 'price',
    'type' => 'number',
    'min'  => 0,
    'step' => '0.01',
];
$fields[] = [
    'name' => __( 'Suffix', 'auto-listings' ),
    'desc' => __( 'Optional text after price.', 'auto-listings' ),
    'id'   => $prefix . 'price_suffix',
    'type' => 'text',
];

$fields = apply_filters( 'auto_listings_metabox_details', $fields );

ksort( $fields );

return [
    'id'         => $prefix . 'details',
    'title'      => __( 'Details', 'auto-listings' ),
    'post_types' => 'auto-listing',
    'fields'     => $fields,
    'context'    => 'side',
];
```

And here is the code I built to call shortcode with parameters, but I only know pass 1 custom fields at one time.

```
public function listings( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        [
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order'   => 'asc',
            'number'  => '20',
            'price' => ''
        ],
        $atts
    );

    $query_args = [
        'post_type'           => $post-type,
        'post_status'         => 'publish',
        'meta_key'            => '_al_listing_price',
        'orderby'             => 'meta_value',
        'meta_value' => $atts['price'],
        'order'               => $atts['order'],                
        'posts_per_page'      => $atts['number'],
    ];

    return $this->listing_loop( $query_args, $atts, 'listings' );
}
```

Any helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this several different ways. Need to know how you are passing the 1 custom field in your current shortcode.

It seems like you might be doing it like this:

```
[your_short_code price="how_are_you_setting_this"]
```

if this is the case then you can just add more attributes like this:

```
[your_short_code price="how_are_you_setting_this" next_field="set_this_field"]

// From your code above with adjustments.
public function listings( $atts ) {
global $post;
// You can add on to the default atts.
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        [
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order'   => 'asc',
            'number'  => '20',
            'price' => '',
            'next_field' =>'',
        ],
        $atts
    );

// Not exactly sure what you are trying to do here.
    $query_args = [
        'post_type'           => $post->post_type,
        'post_status'         => 'publish',
        'meta_key'            => '_al_listing_price',
        'orderby'             => 'meta_value',
        'meta_value'          => $atts['price'],
        'order'               => $atts['order'],                
        'posts_per_page'      => $atts['number'],
    ];

    return $this->listing_loop( $query_args, $atts, 'listings' );
}
```

Another way of doing it is like this:

```
// notice that the attribute fields has multiple fields separated by commas.
[your_short_code fields="how_are_you_setting_this,set_next_field,and_set_next"]
```

If you go with the separated commas then in your shortcode on the php side you will need to do as follows:

```
// From your code above with adjustments.
    public function listings( $atts ) {
    global $post;
    // You can add on to the default atts.
        $atts = shortcode_atts(
            [
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order'   => 'asc',
                'number'  => '20',
                'fields' => '',
            ],
            $atts
        );

        // This will make an array out of your comma separated fields.
        $fields = explode( ',', $atts['fields'] );

    // Not exactly sure what you are trying to do here.
        $query_args = [
            'post_type'           => $post->post_type,
            'post_status'         => 'publish',
            'meta_key'            => '_al_listing_price',
            'orderby'             => 'meta_value',
            'meta_value'          => $atts['price'],
            'order'               => $atts['order'],                
            'posts_per_page'      => $atts['number'],
        ];

        return $this->listing_loop( $query_args, $atts, 'listings' );
    }
```

Hope this helps you.